# Getting error: "Invalid Response: The deployment could not be found"

Tags: javascript, testnet

I'm trying to get account data with the following code:

```
const iota = new IOTA({
  'host': 'https://testnet140.tangle.works',
  'port': 443
});

const seed = //my seed
iota.api.getAccountData(seed, function(error, accountData) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log(accountData);
  }
})
```

But I am getting the error: `Invalid Response: The deployment could not be found`.

**Update**

As a test I tried making a curl call to `https://testnet140.tangle.works:443`to get node info and it worked.

```
curl https://testnet140.tangle.works:443 \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-IOTA-API-Version: 1' \
  -d '{"command": "getNodeInfo"}'
```

However, making the same call in Postman results in a `404` and a message of `The deployment could not be found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I thought this looked like an issue with the iota.lib.js, it appears that it is actually a problem with the testnet node I was using, `https://testnet140.tangle.works:443`. Switching to `http://p103.iotaledger.net:14700` solves my issue.

**Update**

It appears that `https://testnet140.tangle.works` without the port is working while having the port results in the error.